# Fallout: New Vegas freezes when the game loads data. Is this a frequent issue?

Tags: ps3, fallout-new-vegas

I picked up Fallout New Vegas the other day for the PS3 and I am constantly plagued the game freezing.  I've done some quick searches but haven't found anything that I would call "definitive" on the situation.

When the situation occurs it seems to happen at the same time the game is loading data, as I often see small pauses when the game is loading up data.  Some time those pauses become full on freezes.

Does anyone know whether this is a frequent issue for other PS3 players as well?

Any word on when a patch will get issued out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're certainly not alone. There are thousands of similar complaints littered across the web. [Bethesda say they will release a patch for the console versions "very soon"](http://forums.bethsoft.com/index.php?showtopic=1125221&st=0). It's already been published for Steam (PC) users.

Comment: The things that get past QA these days just amazes me.  Seriously my console locked up a dozen times in one afternoon.  Are you telling me a play tester wouldn't have found that?

Comment: chances are QA did find it but it was released anyway to meet deadlines. Thats the problem with games nowadays - they can just ship it in any old state and patch it late

Comment: I agree.  With consoles that are always connected to the internet the release date is now something that can alway be met and "fixed" later.

Comment: I wonder how gamers who do *not* have their consoles connected to the net feel? AFAIK, there's plenty of them, too. The patch is out now, but my PS3 still crashes quite often while playing New Vegas. Some locations, like Westside also make the game a slideshow (there's no framerate shown, but I wouldn't be surprised if it drops to 10fps or below). FNV is one of the worst written (code) games I ever played (and one of the best written scenarios)...

Comment: In my opinion the latest patch on the PS3 has actually made the stability worse than the original release.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't happen to me so often, but I was plagued by it in Fallout 3.  The only (temporary) fix I could find was to delete the game data (a couple of gigabytes) and then turn off the console, turn it back on and run the game again.  it is very annoying because it takes ten minutes or so for the game data to be loaded back again.

Perhaps you already tried this, but if not, it might help.